# R: Adding error bars to ggplot2 barplot with discrete (count) y-axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

While there are many posts on SO regarding adding error bars to barplots in ggplot2 when the y-axis is a continuous variable and the x-axis are discrete categories, I am trying to add error bars to a barplot where the y-axis is discrete. More specifically, the y-axis is the count of observations in my data for the specified nominal group on the x-axis.

For example, suppose I have the below plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))

# Number of cars in each class:
g + geom_bar()
```

How do I add error bars for the counts?

Comment: You can still add error bars with `geom_errorbar()`. How wide do you want them?

Comment: Arbitrary. Are you suggesting calculating them by hand from e.g. a Poisson process and then adding them?

Comment: It's not a useful case, but `ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ..count.. * .9, ymax = ..count.. * 1.1), stat = 'count')`